# IOS 64-bit with static library build error

Tags: ios, 64-bit, static-libraries, arm64

I am trying to make my existing project to support 64-bit device as required by Apple.
The project use Three20 as static library.

I have already rebuilt Three320 library with arm64 architecture.

But now my project still got build error "**symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" as below :**

```
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTDefaultStyleSheet", referenced from:

(null): _OBJC_CLASS_$_TitleStyleSheet in SettingsViewController.o

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTStyleSheet", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in DailyInvestmentViewController.o

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTStyledText", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in DailyInvestmentViewController.o

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTStyledTextLabel", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in DailyInvestmentCustomCell.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in DailyInvestmentViewController.o

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTextStyle", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o

(null): "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TTDefaultStyleSheet", referenced from:

(null): _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TitleStyleSheet in SettingsViewController.o

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it.
Thanks a lot.
Sorry my English bad.

Comment: It says symbols not found for i386 in your output, maybe you need to recompile it for the simulator?

Comment: @Roger You need a Fat library having slice for i386-64 architecture also.

Answer (score 0):

As you state, you have rebuild the lib for arm, not for i386.
But you try to build for 64bit simulator use, which is i386_64. You still do not have the lib supporting that platform.

I suggest to build a second versio of the lib for i386 platform for use in simulator builds only with 64bit support. This way your production lib stays smaller with arm only binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue this morning with my own static library that had already been built for i386 and x86_64.

What fixed it for me was changing the Architectures attribute in Build Settings to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT).  I cleaned, restarted Xcode, and it worked.

Good luck.

Comment: With Xcode 6.1, I rebuilt the library with architecture x86_64, then successfully rebuilt the main app without error